# Reassigning elements of array of custom class

Tags: c++, class

I have an array of a custom class called `Rect rects[5];`
This is what the `Rect` class looks like (do keep in mind that Vector2 and DrawRectangle comes from the c++ library raylib):

```cpp
class Rect
{
public:
    Vector2 position;
    Vector2 size;
    void Draw()
    {
        DrawRectangle(position.x, position.y, size.x, size.y, BLACK);
    }
    Rect(Vector2 v_position, Vector2 v_size)
    {
        position = v_position;
        size = v_size;
    }
};
```

And in the code (separately) I have:

```cpp
rects[0] = Rect(Vector2{100, 100}, Vector2{50, 70});
```

Whenever I compile the code, I get this error:

```
game/main.cpp: error: ‘rects’ does not name a type
      | rects[0] = Rect(Vector2{100, 100}, Vector2{50, 70});
      | ^~~~~
```

I was expecting the array to be mutable (I come from a python background where lists are mutable), but maybe something is wrong in my class definition?

I tried using `Rect rects[0]` but it didn't work.

Comment: Could be looking at too-late an error message. `Rect rects[5];` is doomed to an ill fate because `Rect(Vector2 v_position, Vector2 v_size)` cannot be trivially initialized and won't compile.   later code will report an error because `rects` does not exist because of the previous error.

Comment: It won't take too much work to put together a [mre] (MRE) to fill in the holes in the question and make it answerable without guesswork. Even better, the real reason we ask for MREs is it's hard to make a good one without focusing the code on the problem so much that the problem and solution become obvious.

Comment: How many `Rect` elements do you want? Is it a fixed number that you know before compiling or is it something you'll have to figure out in runtime?

Comment: The error message suggests that line `rects[0] = Rect(Vector2{100, 100}, Vector2{50, 70});` is not placed in any function (where it should be). If you come from Python, there's *a lot* of things you have to learn. You can't apply Python logic to C++ in almost every case.

Comment: In C++ there is no such thing as an empty spot in an array, so when you define an array, you have to initialize every element of the array. In this case that means invoking the 
 `Rect(Vector2 v_position, Vector2 v_size)`  constructor. This means you must supply the appropriate arguments for all five `Rect`s in `Rect rects[5]`. You can assign them new values later, but you MUST initialize.

Comment: Arrays in C++ are derived from the arrays of the C programming language, and C arrays are an elegant solution to common problems of the 1960s and 1970s. By modern standards they are extremely stupid, and most of the time you'll find you want a library container like `std::vector` or `std::array` instead.

Comment: @yksisarvinen thank you! that fixed it! i put `rects[0] = Rect(Vector2{100, 100}, Vector2{50, 70});` inside of `main()`

Comment: @user4581301 sorry for not creating an MRE, i thought my information was enough for help, but thanks for help anyway!

Comment: Don't think about asking a Stack Overflow question as a personal appeal for help.  Stack Overflow is a library of answers. To make it work, people need to ask questions that can be answered and also be understood by future askers. If the future programmers cannot determine whether or not your question also applies to their problem, it's harder to make use of the answers. We can't answer this question because there are too many different ways you could get into this sort of trouble. We've just outlined the more common ways  in the comments.

Comment: Make the MRE, and if you still have a question when you're done, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77573929/edit) the question to add the MRE. If you have solved the problem, consider adding the MRE anyway and self-answering so future askers can learn. But before self answering, search the site to make sure the question hasn't been answered before. C++ is an old language and Stack Overflow's an old site. There's not much a C++ beginner can ask that hasn't already been asked.